# Animate armature from 3d joint locations

Tags: modeling, python, animation, scripting, rigging

I have a simple human armature that I am trying to animate based on real-world 3d coordinates. These are coordinates of 21 distinct joints in (x, y, z) format. Based on the way that I generated my data, I cannot guarantee that the bones are globally the same length, but I assume that it will be close. To combat this, I produced an armature that has a parented joint structure, but where the bones are disconnected. It looks like this:
[image: Simple armature with disconnect bones, but properly parented]

I want to set the bone head and tail position of every bone in my armature, and then animate it from the data that I have using the python API.

I have a super simple script that I am working from to read in my data and assign the proper objects. I was attempting to assign positions to head and tail, but I see that the pose_bones are read-only for those objects. Thus, I created a few extra bones and just set .location to see if I could get my bones to move. My script translates all of my bones, but every frame appears identical (not to mention extremely disconnected) - even though my data is not constant in every frame.

Here is that script:

```
with open('frames.json') as f:
    frame_data = json.load(f)

# frame_data is a dictionary of dictionaries that looks like this: 
# {'frame_0' : {'joint_name': (x, y, z), ... }, ..., 'frame_n': {} }

rig = bpy.data.objects['metarig']

for frame_num, joints in frame_data.items():
    bpy.context.scene.frame_set(int(frame_num))
    for joint_name, joint_positions in joints.items():
        if "hand" not in joint_name:
            rig.pose.bones[joint_name].location = joint_positions
    rig.keyframe_insert(data_path="location", index=-1)
```

I assume that I am accessing the wrong object to update positions, or that I have to switch back and forth between edit mode and pose mode in every frame, but I am not sure where to turn.

When I run my code, I get some craziness that looks like this:
[image: A nonsensical frame produced by my script]

I am suspecting that the giant gaps are because I am not updating the head and tail positions. How does one do that explicitly? And is there any reason in particular why every frame is identical?

I am completely new to blender, and this is the first time that I have ever done a project with the software, so I apologize if my question is a little elementary.

Comment: I'm working on this exact question.
I have thought about calculating the translation and rotation matrices between each frame and then applying that transform in POSE mode. Doesn't work out exactly since I haven't figured out how to get the inverse homogenous rotation matrix.. Some things I've come to realize. You need to be in POSE mode to edit the pose, EDIT mode to edit head and tail (which is relevant to your joints), and OBJECT mode for keyframes (I think, not sure on the last one.) `Location` is also different from `head` and `tail` So far the `bpy.struct` for `PoseBone` has been really

Comment: possibily this is due to the way bone are encoded in the input file. The way blender defines bones is not (always) the way other software does it.